# How are isometries one-to-one?

Tags: geometry, functions, metric-spaces, isometry

I am taking a class on geometry, and am a bit confused by this paragraph in our textbook:

> Each isometry is one~to-one-because points at nonzero distance cannot have images at zero distance-but it is not clear that each isometry is onto

I imagine one-to-one just means injective, and onto means surjective.

Firstly, we are saying every isometry is injective, meaning every point in the plane is sent to one and only one point in the transformed plane. I imaigine this comes from the property of metric preservance, but how would one go about proving this?

Secondly, to be surjective in this situation would mean every point in the transformed plane is mapped to by some point in the untransformed plane. Again, how would one show this? I imagine the span of the matrix of the isometry may be useful, but I am unsure.

Comment: Wikipedia says, "In mathematics, an isometry (or congruence, or congruent transformation) is a distance-preserving transformation between metric spaces, usually assumed to be bijective." So if *bijective* is not baked into the cake of your book's definition of *isometry*, then that leads me to ask, what is your textbook's definition of isometry?

Comment: @AdamRubinson A euclidean isometry, or isometry of ]R2, is a function f : ]R2 ---+ ]R2 which preserves euclidean distance.

Comment: You stated that injectivity means *every point in the plane is sent to one and only one point in the transformed plane*. But that is not the definition of injectivity. That is simply the definition of a function.

Comment: @AdamRubinson: In a course on Euclidean geometry, surjectivity is not usually assumed, for the following pedagogical reason: even without assuming surjectivity, one can *prove* that every isometry is surjective.

Comment: @LeeMosher after reading the comment below, I can understand why they are injective, name that if $x \not =x2$ then $f(x) \not = f(x2)$, but I am not sure of surjectivity yet

Answer (score 1):

One-to-one is somewhat bad terminology since every function maps one point to only one point (this is the vertical line test). What it means to be one-to-one is that every point in the *image* has only one point which gets mapped to it. The only way for this to fail is if some point in the image is hit by at least two points in the domain. An isometry preserves distances, so since distinct points are at a positive distance from one another, they are mapped to distinct points in the image. (In particular, an isometry never maps distinct points onto the same point, which is zero distance from itself.)

As for onto, it should be clear that things like rotations, translations, and reflections are all isometries and that they are all onto (if it isn’t clear, try to prove it using the definitions). It’s a theorem (not an obvious one) that these are the building blocks of all isometries of the plane, in some sense.

Comment: Let me see if I understood: it is one-to-one bc the distance between any points P1 and P2 is the same as f(P1) and f(P2), and so f(P1) is distinct from f(P2) since they are at positive distance. Also, they rotation, translation, and reflection are onto, because the span of the matrix defining them is full rank? I am still unsure about how rotation, translation, and reflection are onto

Comment: @Shagester: For rotations and reflections, the matrix argument works fine, but translations are not linear maps, so this argument wouldn't work for translations. There is a simple argument from first principles. Say we consider reflection about an axis. To prove this is onto, pick a point in the plane. What is the point which maps to it? Draw some pictures if you have to, but it should be evident all three of these kinds of maps are isometries.

Comment: @Shagester - To show that an isometry $f$ of the plane has to be surjective, pick the vertices of a triangle in its domain. The isometry maps them to the vertices of a congruent triangle in the codomain. Any other point $P$ in the codomain is uniquely identifiable by its distances to these three vertices - it is the common intersection point of three circles about the three vertices. Circles with the same radii about the corresponding vertices can be drawn in the domain, and must intersect in a unique point $P'$. The isometry must carry $P'$ to $P$.